# Android fixed layout 3/4 + 1/4

Tags: android, android-layout

I am struggling with android layout settings. I would like to keep the same fixed size no matter what the content is and want to show everything in the center!

```
---------------------------------
-                       -       -
-                       -       -
-      3/4 (center)     -  1/4  -
-                       -  (ct) -
-                       -       -
-                       -       -
---------------------------------
```

Here is my layout.xml code, but it not works:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

         <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_weight=".25" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:freezesText="false"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text="@string/Runstring" />
         </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

I tried some codes from below and experienced: If I make the `@string/Runstring` = just an "a" or if I make it "..........LONG STRING........." IT is changing the whole layout! It's not keep the 3/4 + 1/4 ratio! Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your layout is that you have defined the width of Parent layout as **wrap_content** you must set this as **fill_parent**. You are dividing the views into some proportion but you have not set the attribute to parent as fill_parent. Thats why it as not able to divide the screen into the right proportion.

Here is your updated layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".25" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:freezesText="false"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text="@string/Runstring" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

layout_weight will work with width set to 0dp. your layout will look like:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

     <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="3" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:freezesText="false"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:text="@string/Runstring" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "layout_weight only works with width set to 0dp". Thats incorrect.

Comment: in my experience i have seen setting it to match_parent or wrap_content produces undesirable. will be good to know what other values work with weight :-)

Comment: Check the updated answer. This was the real problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

In code you can  do it like this

```
metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        height = metrics.heightPixels;
        weight = metrics.weightPixels;//RETURNS THE SCREEN WIDTH
  videosView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                width/4,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  TEXTVIEW1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                3*width/4,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

OR IN XML YOU CAN DO IT LIKE THIS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:freezesText="false"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text="@string/Runstring" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```